# React warning in react-redux connectAdvanced.js

Tags: react-redux

I have a react app using redux, but have started getting these browser warnings from react.

"Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component." (see more of the warning below).

Reading through the comments in this react issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178, it is suggested that the error occurs in the first stack frame after the react frames. Which would suggest that the problem is in connectAdvanced.js in react-redux. Has anyone else seen this? Is it a bug in react-redux?

[image]

Comment: Need to see the code that where this stackTrace leads to , which in your case is Table component

Comment: The Table component is the one from Material UI https://material-ui.com/api/table/. The code also uses react-virtualized https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized.